# Working with Shell script and GRASS

Tags: grass-7.0, shell

So reading this [GRASS/Shell documentation](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Shell_scripting) I decided to test my own for repeat using this lines

`CATS="(v.db.select -c map=training columns=cat)"`
`echo $CATS`
`for i in $CATS`
`do`
    `where="cat = $CATS"`
    `outputname=region_uspo_$CATS`
    `regionname=subset_uspo_$CATS`

`v.extract -o input=training type=area where=$condition output=$outputname
done`

but I keep getting an error message with v.extract

> ERROR: v.extract: Sorry,  is not a valid flag
>   ERROR: v.extract: Sorry,  is not a valid flag
>   ERROR: v.extract: Sorry,  is not a valid parameter
>   ERROR: v.extract: Sorry,  is not a valid parameter

now I've also tried this
`CATS="$(v.db.select -c map=training columns=cat)"`

Can anyone help me figure out where I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I typed before I was able to think and the actual loop was this:

`CATS="$(v.db.select -c map=training columns=cat)"
echo $CATS
for i in $CATS
do 
echo $i 
where="cat=$i" 
v.extract --overwrite input=training@user type=area where=$where output=region_uspo_$i
done`